# Second query works when hard coded but not when I replace the WHERE condition with a POST variable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

I am trying to display the output of the following code in one datatable. Right now, only the output from the first query is displayed. 
This works fine when I replace $opr_emp_id with the hard coded value (say 4563) in the second query - I get both the result sets. 
Here is the sample fetch.php:

```
<?php
//fetch.php

include_once("DB_Config.php");

$data = array();
$opr_emp_id = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["opr_id"]));

$query_PE = "SELECT power_equipment_training.PE_TRAINING_ID AS TRAINING_ID, 
                power_equipment_training.PE_training_name AS TRAINING_NAME, 
                power_equipment_docs.PE_DOC_ID AS DOCUMENT_ID, 
                power_equipment_docs.PE_doc_name AS DOCUMENT_NAME, 
                power_equipment_docs.PE_doc_latest_version AS LATEST_VERSION, 
                emp_power_equipment.PE_doc_version_trained AS VERSION_TRAINED, 
                emp_power_equipment.PE_training_received_date AS TRAINED_DATE, 
                emp_power_equipment.PE_training_validity AS VALIDITY,
                emp_power_equipment.PE_qualification_status AS QUALIFICATION_STATUS 
            FROM emp_power_equipment 
            INNER JOIN ( power_equipment_training INNER JOIN 
                        power_equipment_docs ON 
                        power_equipment_training.PE_TRAINING_ID = power_equipment_docs.PE_TRAINING_ID 
                        )  
                ON emp_power_equipment.PE_DOC_ID = power_equipment_docs.PE_DOC_ID 
                WHERE emp_power_equipment.emp_id='".$opr_emp_id."'";

$result_PE = mysqli_query($conn, $query_PE);
while($row_PE = mysqli_fetch_array($result_PE)) {
     $sub_array = array();
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row_PE["DOCUMENT_ID"].'" data-column="DOCUMENT_ID">' . $row_PE["DOCUMENT_ID"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row_PE["DOCUMENT_ID"].'" data-column="DOCUMENT_NAME">' . $row_PE["DOCUMENT_NAME"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row_PE["DOCUMENT_ID"].'" data-column="TRAINING_ID">' . $row_PE["TRAINING_ID"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row_PE["DOCUMENT_ID"].'" data-column="TRAINING_NAME">' . $row_PE["TRAINING_NAME"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row_PE["DOCUMENT_ID"].'" data-column="VERSION_TRAINED">' . $row_PE["VERSION_TRAINED"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row_PE["DOCUMENT_ID"].'" data-column="LATEST_VERSION">' . $row_PE["LATEST_VERSION"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row_PE["DOCUMENT_ID"].'" data-column="TRAINED_DATE">' . $row_PE["TRAINED_DATE"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row_PE["DOCUMENT_ID"].'" data-column="VALIDITY">' . $row_PE["VALIDITY"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row_PE["DOCUMENT_ID"].'" data-column="QUALIFICATION_STATUS">' . $row_PE["QUALIFICATION_STATUS"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" id="'.$row_PE["DOCUMENT_ID"].'">Delete</button>';
     $data[] = $sub_array;
}
$query_EMS = "SELECT EMS_procedure_training.EMS_TRAINING_ID AS TRAINING_ID, 
                EMS_procedure_training.EMS_training_name AS TRAINING_NAME, 
                EMS_procedure_docs.EMS_DOC_ID AS DOCUMENT_ID, 
                EMS_procedure_docs.EMS_doc_name AS DOCUMENT_NAME, 
                EMS_procedure_docs.EMS_doc_latest_version AS LATEST_VERSION, 
                emp_EMS_procedure.EMS_doc_version_trained AS VERSION_TRAINED, 
                emp_EMS_procedure.EMS_training_received_date AS TRAINED_DATE, 
                emp_EMS_procedure.EMS_training_validity AS VALIDITY, 
                emp_EMS_procedure.EMS_qualification_status AS QUALIFICATION_STATUS 
            FROM emp_EMS_procedure 
                INNER JOIN ( EMS_procedure_training 
                            INNER JOIN EMS_procedure_docs ON 
                                EMS_procedure_training.EMS_TRAINING_ID = EMS_procedure_docs.EMS_TRAINING_ID
                            ) 
                    ON emp_EMS_procedure.EMS_DOC_ID = EMS_procedure_docs.EMS_DOC_ID 
            WHERE emp_EMS_procedure.emp_id='".$opr_emp_id."'";

$result_EMS = mysqli_query($conn, $query_EMS);
while($row_EMS = mysqli_fetch_array($result_EMS)) {
     $sub_array = array();
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row_EMS["DOCUMENT_ID"].'" data-column="DOCUMENT_ID">' . $row_EMS["DOCUMENT_ID"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row_EMS["DOCUMENT_ID"].'" data-column="DOCUMENT_NAME">' . $row_EMS["DOCUMENT_NAME"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row_EMS["DOCUMENT_ID"].'" data-column="TRAINING_ID">' . $row_EMS["TRAINING_ID"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row_EMS["DOCUMENT_ID"].'" data-column="TRAINING_NAME">' . $row_EMS["TRAINING_NAME"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row_EMS["DOCUMENT_ID"].'" data-column="VERSION_TRAINED">' . $row_EMS["VERSION_TRAINED"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row_EMS["DOCUMENT_ID"].'" data-column="LATEST_VERSION">' . $row_EMS["LATEST_VERSION"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row_EMS["DOCUMENT_ID"].'" data-column="TRAINED_DATE">' . $row_EMS["TRAINED_DATE"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row_EMS["DOCUMENT_ID"].'" data-column="VALIDITY">' . $row_EMS["VALIDITY"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<div data-id="'.$row_EMS["DOCUMENT_ID"].'" data-column="QUALIFICATION_STATUS">' . $row_EMS["QUALIFICATION_STATUS"] . '</div>';
     $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" id="'.$row_EMS["DOCUMENT_ID"].'">Delete</button>';
     $data[] = $sub_array;
}
$output = array(
    "draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
    "data"    => $data
);

echo json_encode($output);
```

?>

The AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    fetch_data();

    function fetch_data() {
        var dataTable = $('#opr_training-dt').DataTable({
                    "processing" : true,
                    "serverSide" : false,
                    "order" : [],
                    "ajax" : {
                        url:"fetch.php",
                        type:"post",
                        data:{opr_id:<?php echo $opr_emp_id; ?>}                                                    
                }
        });
    }
}
```

The front-end:

```
<table id="opr_training-dt" class="table table-hover table-bordered responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">DOCUMENT ID</th>
            <th scope="col">DOCUMENT NAME</th>
            <th scope="col">TRAINING ID</th>
            <th scope="col">TRAINING NAME</th>
            <th scope="col">VERSION TRAINED</th>
            <th scope="col">LATEST VERSION</th>
            <th scope="col">TRAINED DATE</th>
            <th scope="col">VALIDITY</th>
            <th scope="col">QUALIFICATION STATUS</th>
            <th></th>                               
        </tr>
    </thead>

</table>
```

I have no idea why this is happening. I am a newbie to PHP. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: DIE the query as a string to evaluate it manually.

Comment: All that UPPER case hurts my eyes and all these full table names makes it painful to read and this `INNER  JOIN( table INNER JOIN on ... ) on ...`. what's `echo $query_PE;`

Comment: **Error checking** but if you cannot be bothered, Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`
 to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes I do use prepared statements. This is just a try in my localhost for fetching all the record sets. I tried reporting the errors and this is what I get: "DataTables warning: table id=opr_training-dt - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1". Any idea why hard-coded queries work fine and not the POST variable?

Comment: Well of course I believe you. Oh and you dont actually check that the form has been submitted before using `$_POST` values, which wont exist if the form has not been submitted

Comment: @RiggsFolly there's no form...

Comment: @Don'tPanic Hmm, that could explain why `$_POST["opr_id"]` is not setting `$opr_emp_id` to anything useful :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Well if that's the case, the first query wouldn't work either. But I get the datatable populated with the result set from the first query. It is just the second one that doesn't work with the POST variable.

Comment: @RiggsFolly it's in the ajax request, right?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Right of course it is